# Items are going out of container even with using percentages in width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a header with two items a site title and a navbar. And header is created by using the percentage units so the items would work according to the width of the screen but When I am decreasing the width of the screen the navbar is going out of the container even though by using percentages. I surfed the internet to find my answer and there are many similar questions on StackOverflow like that but no of them is working on my issue.
So can anyone tell me why it's happening and how to fix this?

Here is my code

```css
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    position:absolute;
}
/* html{
     border:5px solid blue;
} */
*,::before,::after{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;   
}
body{
    font-family:sans-serif ;
}
.container{
   width:100%;
}
.header{
    width:100%;
    padding:.5em .5em;
}
.header-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:.8em 0em;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
}
.site-title{
  margin-left: 2em;
  font-size:2.3em;
  font-weight:400;
    

}
.site-title-span{
    font-weight:750;
    color:#E47700;
}
.nav{
    margin-right:2%;
    width:45%;
    font: size 1em;;
}
.nav ul{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 font-size:1.5em;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav ul li{
  margin-right:12%;
}
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:black;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding:6px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background:#FEBD33;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition: .3s all ease;
}

.active{
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color: #FEBD33;
    color: white;
    padding:0 12px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="header">
            <!--header open-->
            <div class="header-wrapper">
                <div class="site-title">
                    <p>

                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>ee
                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>uzz
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--header closed-->
```

Comment: You've an [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) problem. Size values are calculated relative to the offsetParent element, that must not be statically positioned.

Comment: You should add togglable navbar for smaller screens

Comment: @Teemu Could you tell me how fix that

Comment: Position the ancestor elements relative or absolute.

Comment: Remove the `width` from `nav` and in `.nav ul li`, use an absolute value for the margin like `1em`: https://jsfiddle.net/s15py6kd/

Comment: @Teemu I tried to give position relative to .site-title and the div.nav but it doesn't works

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks a lot for your answer it works and may I know Why its happening

Comment: The width set in the nav `45%` is not enough for those `.nav ul li` as they already taking some width with their content as well as some extra 12% and plus that `.nav ul` has flex's default wrap value set to no-wrap so the content will always exceed the header width and not wrapping

Comment: The width of the nav is not enough, basically. Try to avoid "fixed" widths (even percentage ones) until you cannot achieve your goal any other way.

Comment: @konekoya Thanks a lot for your comment and answer. Now I understood why it's happening and if you think this question seems useful to the community you can upvote this.

Comment: @ChrisG SIr your Js fiddle answer is amazing Thanks a lot for the answer and when should I use percentages or fixed width's and if you think this question seems useful to the community you can upvote this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently sets a `45%` width for the nav, and that's not enough for all `.nav ul li` which has its own content width plus that extra `12%` margin-right. Also, `nav ul` has flex's default wrap value set to `no-wrap` and so the content will always exceed the header width as well as not wrapping at all.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em .5em;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: .8em 0em;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.site-title {
  margin-left: 2em;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: 400;


}

.site-title-span {
  font-weight: 750;
  color: #E47700;
}

.nav {
  margin-right: 2%;
  /* I don't think you need this, either remove it or give a bigger value, so you
  nav won't wrap even when there's enough space */
  /* width: 45%; */
  font: size 1em;
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Add this line so the nav item can wrap when needed */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav ul li {
  /* margin-right: 12%; */

  /* Use a smaller margin here */
  margin-right: 1rem
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #FEBD33;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.active {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #FEBD33;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <!--header open-->
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="site-title">
        <p>

          <span class="site-title-span">B</span>ee
          <span class="site-title-span">B</span>uzz
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--header closed-->
```

Comment: Your comment above is a better answer than this ;) Seriously, don't post code-only answers. OP is primarily interested in the cause of the overflow.